# Failed to get properties: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1

Tags: 16.04, upstart, docker

I used Ubuntu server 16.04.4 LTS and begin with containerization on Docker.

I am using the upstart kernel on which I am booting and as soon as I run the following command:

```
systemctl docker status
```

it returns the following error message:

```
Failed to get properties: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1.
```

any help is welcome and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the following command worked:

```
sudo service docker status
```